# jquery easyui datagrid cannot show data with the method'loadData'

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datagrid

I want to use datagrid to show some json data, And for some other reason I used the method 'loadData' to load the fetched json. It seems that the json has been fetched successfully (the browser alert correctly )but the following code can't work and the table(#dg) is blank.

```html
@(category:String)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title id="category">@category</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@routes.Assets.at("themes/default/easyui.css")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@routes.Assets.at("themes/icon.css")">
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
        margin: 0px;
        }

        a {
        color: #21759b;
        text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:hover {
        color: #0f3647;
        text-decoration: underline;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("js/jquery.easyui.min.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("js/datagrid-scrollview.js")"></script>
        @*<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at(js/jquery.flot.min.js)"></script>*@
        @*<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at(js/jquery.flot.time.min.js)"></script>*@
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var field; //当前排序字段
        var rows; //数据
        var scrollLeft = 0; //横向滚动条位置，可恢复
        var scrollEvent = function(e) { //滚动条事件
        scrollLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();
        };

        //阻止连带滚动外部窗口
        var preventScrollParent = function(e, d) {
        var t = $(this);
        if (d > 0 && t.scrollTop() <= 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        } else {
        if (d < 0 && (t.scrollTop() >= t.get(0).scrollHeight - t.innerHeight())) {
        e.preventDefault();
        }
        }
        };

        $(function () {
        //        if ( parent.location.hostname != self.location.hostname ) {
        //        self.location = "/nopermission.html" ;
        //        }

        field = "commentnum" ;
        $("#dg").width($(self).width())
        .height($(self).height())
        .datagrid({
                url: "http://localhost:9000/json/"+ $("#category" ).text() + "/" + field,
                method:"GET",
        loadMsg : 'Loading',
        view : scrollview,
        pageSize : 50,
        autoRowHeight : false,
        rownumbers : true,
        singleSelect : true,
        border : false,
        striped : true,
        onLoadSuccess : loadFinish,
        columns:[[
        {field:'id',title:'id',width:100},
        {field:'name',title:'名字',width:400},
        {field:'url',title:'访问购买',width:220,align:'right'},
        //        {field:'imgsrc',title:'图片',width:100,align:'right'},
        {field:'price',title:'价格',width:60,align:'right'},
        {field:'commentnum',title:'评论数',width:60,align:'right'},
        {field:'likerate',title:'好评率',width:60,align:'right'},
        {field:'category',title:'品类',width:60,align:'right'}
        ]]
        }) ;
        setTimeout(loaddata, 50);
        });

        //加载某列排序的数据
        function loaddata() {
        $("#dg").datagrid("loading");

        $.getJSON("http://localhost:9000/json/"+ $("#category" ).text() + "/" + field, {}, function(result) {
        rows = result.rows;
        $("#dg").datagrid('loadData', rows);
        });
        }

        //加载完成后处理
        function loadFinish() {
        $("#dg").datagrid("loaded");
        $(".datagrid-view2 .datagrid-body").scrollLeft(scrollLeft);
        $(".datagrid-header-row>td").css("font-weight", "normal");
        $(".datagrid-header-row>td[field='" + field + "'").css("font-weight", "bold");
        $(".datagrid-header-row>td").click(function() {
        clickTitle($(this));
        });
        $(".datagrid-row a").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        })
        $(".datagrid-view2 .datagrid-body").scroll(scrollEvent);
        $(".datagrid-view2 .datagrid-body").bind('mousewheel', preventScrollParent);
        }


        //标题点击排序事件
        function clickTitle(title) {
        if (title.attr("field") && title.attr("field") != field && (title.attr("field") == "price"||title.attr("field")=="likerate"||title.attr("field")=="commentnum")) {
        scrollLeft = $(".datagrid-view2 .datagrid-body").scrollLeft();
        field = title.attr("field");
        $(".datagrid-view2 .datagrid-body").unbind("scroll", scrollEvent);
        $(".datagrid-view2 .datagrid-body").unbind('mousewheel', preventScrollParent);
        loaddata();
        }
        }

        //当前排序列加粗
        function cellStyle(colname) {
        return function(value, row, index) {
        if (colname == field) return 'font-weight:bold;';
        else return '';
        }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="dg"></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your snippet needs a little HTML and links to your libraries to run.

Comment: i think you need to unbind the first datagrid and than bind the second

Comment: yes I checked the elements and find that the datagrid didnot bind the table I defined in the <body>,why is that?